# FlatStyle.System raise strange MouseHover event

Tags: c#, winforms

With the following code, when i move the mouse into the button and click it, the final value of *result* is 2 instead of 1.

```
static int result = 0;

private void button2_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   result++;
}

private void button2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   button2.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
}
```

I had tried different setting:

1. Using *MouseEnter* instead of *MouseHover* give *result = 1*
2. Only changing of FlatStyle to System will trigger MouseHover one more time after button is clicked.
   If the FlatStyle of button is originally FlatStyle.System, give *result = 1*;
   If the FlatStyle is changed to others Style(popup, flat), give *result = 1*;

So i guess the problem lies with the FlatStyle set to FlatStyle.System, anyone can explains this to me?

Comment: as far as i know, mouse hover events continue to generate as you move your mouse pointer over the button. how are you be so certain that you're generating only one mouse hover event?

Comment: @Donotalo i simply add label.text = result.ToString() in the MouseHover event, and the final string shown in label is "2".

Comment: i thought the MouseHover event occurs when mouse is rest/stay in a button for a certain time after entering the control only. So whether the mouse is rest or move ,as long as it does not move out from the control, it should not get triggered again?

Comment: i think if you move mouse pointer over the button, the mouse hover event will be generated continuously. if the pointer is kept at rest, then the event won't be generated. you can try to add consol output in the hover event handler, then move mouse pointer over the button and see how many output you get.

Comment: just tested, the mouse need to leave the button first to trigger the MouseHover again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly common quirk in Winforms.  You can visualize what's going with this code:

```
    private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0:X}, {1}", button1.Handle, DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
        result++;
    }
```

Look in the Output window for the displayed diagnostic.  On mine:

```
12780286, 03:04:10.7619696
12780286, 03:04:16.2935137
12780286, 03:04:20.1062178
12780286, 03:04:23.9970596
Click
12845822, 03:04:28.9191911
12845822, 03:04:32.3099880
```

Note how the Handle property value changed after the click.  In other words, the physical Windows window changed.  This happened because you changed the FlatStyle property.  Winforms implements this by *destroying* the button control window and recreating it.  If you look really close then you can actually see this, the button briefly flickers.

There are a few properties that are implemented like this, they are "heavy" properties that requires the window to be recreated since the style flags changed.  Style flags that are passed in the native CreateWindowEx() call.  A change in those style flags requires another call to CreateWindowEx().

This tends to have side-effects.  Destroying the old window causes its state to be lost.  Winforms tries to restore the state of the new window as best it can, but there are a few it cannot get to.  The "window was hovered" state is one of them.  Clearly the new window has that internal state flag set to false.  Which is why you get the MouseHover event again.  You'll need to work around this quirk.